# Blogger xml export to Wordpress (file too big, 1Gb)

Tags: xml, wordpress, import, blogger

I was tasked with converting a blogger blog to wordpress. Once I downloaded the client's backup, I saw that it had 1Gb+. I tried Blogger Importer with no luck (memory limit) and then decided on Blogger Importer Extended which worked great for the posts (14k) but has taken 2 weeks to import half of the total comments (total: 600k) and now stopped importing.

I have tried to split the huge file with no luck, looked everywhere online.

Anyone have any experience with huge xml files? How can I get this to work?